# Error occurring while installing and importing pynput

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

So I am trying to install and import pynput in VSCode but its showing me an error every time I try to do it. I used VSCode's in-built terminal to install it using pip and typed the following :
`pip install pynput` but this error is shown : `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\vicks\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\vicks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pynput': The system cannot find the file specified`

After receiving the following error, I tried using CMD to install it but the same error is shown. I also tried using `python pip install pynput` and it shows `Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.` even though I have python 3.9.7 and I have selected it as my interpreter in VSCode and I have IDLE(Python 64 bit) installed. How may I resolve the following error? Any help regarding the same is appreciated

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as an in-built terminal in VS code. When you open a terminal in VS Code, it opens the default, which on Windows is usually equivalent to opening up CMD.

If you selected Python 3.9.7 as your default interpreter in VS Code, it does not mean that it will visible to your CMD / terminal. It just means that the VS Code IDE will refer to that instance of Python when launching the program from VS Code itself using the green button (or F5), and when scanning your code to point out missing packages, etc.

CMD will only automatically detect your Python if it's in your PATH environment variable. You should add the Python 3.9.7 base and Scripts path to this.

Also, it would be best if you could first uninstall conflicting versions (like your 3.8.x) of Python and remove them from PATH, assuming that this won't cause any problems for you. Perhaps keep a record all the installed packages in this old version of Python for future reference using `pip freeze` or `pip list`.

Comment: ah ok, wasn't aware that terminal isn't of VSCode, thanks for informing :)
Also thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Check if `c:\users\vicks\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe` exists by typing `cd c:\users\vicks\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32`